# how to close the dropdown popup on clicking of outside the dropdown popup window?

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-compose

I am Using jetbrain compose 2020.3.3 version and i am implementing Dropdown example similar as mentioned below code. as per my analysis "DropDownmenu" internally  using the "Popup" and by default popup focusable is false and there is no option in "Dropdownmenu" to make it true so when dropdown list is expanded ,Clicking outside ther dropdownlist is not closing dropdown list. it seems Expanded dropdown list is acting as blocking popup
`

```
@Composable
    fun DropdownDemo() {
        var expanded = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val items = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
        val disabledValue = "B"
        var selectedIndex = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)) {
            Text(items[selectedIndex.value],modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable(onClick = { expanded.value = true }).background(
                Color.Gray))
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded.value,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded.value = false },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(
                    Color.Red)
            ) {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        selectedIndex.value = index
                        expanded.value = false
                    }) {
                        val disabledText = if (s == disabledValue) {
                            " (Disabled)"
                        } else {
                            ""
                        }
                        Text(text = s + disabledText)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: which version of android compose are you using?

Comment: I have windows application developed in intellij IDE using jetbrain compose 2020.3.3

Comment: It should be the default behavior. Which version of compose are you using?

Comment: I am  using  0.3.0 build 152 version (https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/releases/tag/0.3.0-build152) and default behavior is not there  for dropdown